# Implementing a generic Vector in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement a generic (mathematical) vector in Scala, and I'm running into a couple of issues of how to do it properly:

1) How do you handle + and - such that operating on a `Vector[Int]` and a `Vector[Double]` would return a `Vector[Double]`? In short, how would I go about doing auto promotion of numeric types (preferably taking advantage of Scala's auto promotion)? Because using `implicit n: Numeric[T]` only works if the types of both vectors are the same.

2) Related, how should I define a * operation such that it takes in any Numeric type, and return a vector of the right numeric type? That is, a `Vector[Int] * 2.0` would return a `Vector[Double]`.

This is my current code (which doesn't behave as I would want it):

```
case class Vector2[T](val x: T, val y: T)(implicit n: Numeric[T]) {
  import n._

  def length = sqrt(x.toDouble() * x.toDouble() + y.toDouble() * y.toDouble())
  def unary_- = new Vector2(-x, -y)

  def +(that: Vector2) = new Vector2(x + that.x, y + that.y)
  def -(that: Vector2) = new Vector2(x - that.x, y - that.y)

  def *(s: ???) = new Vector2(x * s, y * s)
}
```

### Update

After a lot of thought, I've decided to accept Chris K's answer, because it works for all the situations I've asked about, despite the verbosity of the type class solution (the numeric types in Scala are Byte, Short, Int, Long, Float, Double, BigInt, BigDecimal, which makes for a very fun time implementing all the operations between each possible pair of types).

I've upvoted both answers, because they're both excellent answers. And I really wish Gabriele Petronella's answer worked for all possible scenarios, if only because it's a very elegant and consise answer. I do hope there'll be some way that it'll work eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few approaches come to mind:

1. Use type classes, an example follows
2. Use Spire, a maths lib for Scala.  A tutorial for vectors using spire can be found [here](http://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/learning_spire_vector_space.html).
3. Combine type classes with [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0) to support vectors of any dimension.  Read Shapeless' support for 'abstracting over arity'.
4. Convert the Vectors to the same type before calling the operations on the Vector.  Gabriele Petronella has given a great example of doing this on Scala 2.10 or later using implicits supplied by the standard Scala library.

Using Type Classes directly:

This approach is somewhat verbose the first time that you create it, as one has to create implicit classes for each combination of values that one wants to support.  But the approach is sound.  More details about type classes can be read [here](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html)

If you want to copy and paste the following code into the scala REPL, be sure to enter ':paste' first.  Otherwise the relationship between the trait and the companion object will not be picked up and the implicit will not be found when one enters 'a+b'.

```
trait NumberLike[A,B,C] {
  def plus(x: A, y: B): C
}
object NumberLike {
  implicit object NumberLikeIntDouble extends NumberLike[Int,Double,Double] {
    def plus(x: Int, y: Double): Double = x + y
  }
  implicit object NumberLikeDoubleInt extends NumberLike[Double,Int,Double] {
    def plus(x: Double, y: Int): Double = x + y
  }
  implicit object NumberLikeIntInt extends NumberLike[Int,Int,Int] {
    def plus(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
  }
}


case class Vector2[T](val x: T, val y: T) {
  def +[B,C](that: Vector2[B])(implicit c:NumberLike[T,B,C]) : Vector2[C] = new Vector2[C](c.plus(this.x,that.x), c.plus(this.y,that.y))
}

val a = Vector2(1,2)
val b = Vector2(2.0,2.0)

a+a
a+b
b+a
```

To add more operators to the vector, like subtraction and divide then add them to the NumberLike trait and follow it through using the plus example above.

Answer (score 9):

A possible approach is to unify the type of the two vectors before applying the operation. By doing so, operations on `Vector2[A]` can alwyas take a `Vector2[A`] as parameter.

A similar approach can be used for multiplication (see the example below).

Using an implicit conversion from `Vector2[A]` to `Vector2[B]` (provided that `Numeric[A]` and `Numeric[B]` both exist and that you have implicit evidence that `A` can be converted to `B`), you can do:

```
case class Vector2[A](val x: A, val y: A)(implicit n: Numeric[A]) {
  import n.mkNumericOps
  import scala.math.sqrt

  def map[B: Numeric](f: (A => B)): Vector2[B] = Vector2(f(x), f(y))

  def length = sqrt(x.toDouble * x.toDouble + y.toDouble * y.toDouble)
  def unary_- = this.map(-_)

  def +(that: Vector2[A]) = Vector2(x + that.x, y + that.y)
  def -(that: Vector2[A]) = Vector2(x - that.x, y - that.y)
  def *[B](s: B)(implicit ev: A => B, nb: Numeric[B]) = this.map(ev(_)).map(nb.times(_, s))
}

object Vector2 {
  implicit def toV[A: Numeric, B: Numeric](v: Vector2[A])(
    implicit ev: A => B // kindly provided by scala std library for all numeric types
  ): Vector2[B] = v.map(ev(_))
}
```

examples:

```
val x = Vector2(1, 2)         //> x  : Solution.Vector2[Int] = Vector2(1,2)
val y = Vector2(3.0, 4.0)     //> y  : Solution.Vector2[Double] = Vector2(3.0,4.0)
val z = Vector2(5L, 6L)       //> z  : Solution.Vector2[Long] = Vector2(5,6)

x + y                         //> res0: Solution.Vector2[Double] = Vector2(4.0,6.0)
y + x                         //> res1: Solution.Vector2[Double] = Vector2(4.0,6.0)
x + z                         //> res2: Solution.Vector2[Long] = Vector2(6,8)
z + x                         //> res3: Solution.Vector2[Long] = Vector2(6,8)
y + z                         //> res4: Solution.Vector2[Double] = Vector2(8.0,10.0)
z + y                         //> res5: Solution.Vector2[Double] = Vector2(8.0,10.0)

x * 2                         //> res6: Solution.Vector2[Int] = Vector2(2,4)
x * 2.0                       //> res7: Solution.Vector2[Double] = Vector2(2.0,4.0)
x * 2L                        //> res8: Solution.Vector2[Long] = Vector2(2,4)
x * 2.0f                      //> res9: Solution.Vector2[Float] = Vector2(2.0,4.0)
x * BigDecimal(2)             //> res10: Solution.Vector2[scala.math.BigDecimal] = Vector2(2,4)
```

---

As per Chris' request in the comments, here's an example of how the implicit conversions chain work

If we run the scala REPL with `scala -XPrint:typer`, we can see the implicits at work explicitly
For instance

```
z + x
```

becomes

```
val res1: Vector2[Long] = $line7.$read.$iw.$iw.$iw.z.+($iw.this.Vector2.toV[Int, Long]($line4.$read.$iw.$iw.$iw.x)(math.this.Numeric.IntIsIntegral, math.this.Numeric.LongIsIntegral, {
        ((x: Int) => scala.this.Int.int2long(x))
      }));
```

which translated to more readable terms is

```
val res: Vector2[Long] = z + toV[Int, Long](x){ i: Int => Int.int2long(i) }
                             ^____________________________________________^
                              the result of this is a Vector[Long]
```

Conversely, `x + z` becomes

```
val res: Vector2[Long] = toV[Int, Long](x){ i: Int => Int.int2long(i) } + z
```

---

The way it works is roughly this:

1. we say `z: V[Long] + x: V[Int]`
2. the compiler sees that there's a method `+[Long, Long]`
3. it looks from a conversion from `V[Int]` to `V[Long]`
4. it finds `toV`
5. it looks for a conversion from `Int` to `Long` as required by `toV`
6. it finds `Int.int2Long`, i.e. a function `Int => Long`
7. it can then use `toV[Int, Long]` i.e. a function `V[Int] => V[Long]`
8. it does `x + toV(z)`

in case we do instead `x: V[Int] + z: V[Long]`

1. the compiler sees that there's a method `+[Int, Int]`
2. it looks from a conversion from `V[Long]` to `V[Int]`
3. it finds `toV`
4. it looks for a conversion from `Long` to `Int` as required by `toV`
5. it can't find it!
6. it sees that there's a method `+[Long, Long]`

and we're back to point 3 of the previous example

---

### Update

As noticed in the comments, there's a problem when doing

```
Vector(2.0, 1.0) * 2.0f
```

This is pretty much the issue:

```
2.0f * 3.0 // 6.0: Double
```

but also

```
2.0 * 3.0f // 6.0: Double
```

So it doesn't matter what's the argument, when mixing doubles and floats we always end up with a double.
Unfortunately we're requiring evidence of `A => B` in order to convert the vector to the type of `s`, but sometimes we actually want to convert `s` to the type of the vector.

We need to handle the two cases. The first naive approach could be

```
def *[B](s: B)(implicit ev: A => B, nb: Numeric[B]): Vector[B] =
  this.map(nb.times(ev(_), s)) // convert A to B
def *[B](s: B)(implicit ev: B => A, na: Numeric[A]): Vector[A] =
  this.map(na.times(_, ev(s))) // convert B to A
```

Neat, right? Too bad it doesn't work: scala does not consider implicit arguments when disambiguating overloaded methods. We have to work around this, using the magnet pattern, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366506/scala-ambiguous-reference-to-overloaded-definition-with-two-implicit-parameters).

```
case class Vector2[A](val x: A, val y: A)(implicit na: Numeric[A]) {
  object ToBOrToA {
    implicit def fromA[B: Numeric](implicit ev: A => B): ToBOrToA[B] = ToBOrToA(Left(ev))
    implicit def fromB[B: Numeric](implicit ev: B => A): ToBOrToA[B] = ToBOrToA(Right(ev))
  }
  case class ToBOrToA[B: Numeric](e: Either[(A => B), (B => A)])

  def *[B](s: B)(implicit ev: ToBOrToA[B], nb: Numeric[B]) = ev match {
    case ToBOrToA(Left(f)) => Vector2[B](nb.times(f(x), s), nb.times(ev(y), s))
    case ToBOrToA(Right(f)) => Vector2[A](na.times(x, f(s)), na.times(y, f(s))
  }
}
```

We have only one `*` method, and we inspect the implicit parameter `ev` to know whether we have to convert everything to the type of the vector or to the type of `s`.

The only drawback of this approach is the result type. `ev match { ... }` returns something that it's supertype of `B with A`, and I still haven't found a workaround for it.

```
val a = x * 2.0    //> a  : Solution.Vector2[_ >: Double with Int] = Vector2(2.0,4.0)
val b = y * 2      //> b  : Solution.Vector2[_ >: Int with Double] = Vector2(6.0,8.0)
```

Comment: Nice approach, I like.  This approach did not work for me using Scala 2.9 (yes I am still stuck on that) but it does work a treat on 2.10.  It would be good to document how the implicit scanning for the conversion works both for x+z and z+x.  It is fairly obvious when Double is on the LHS, but not so much when Long is LHS.

Comment: This works really well, and I really like it because it's nicely concise. The only part where it seems to not work is if we do `y * 2.0f`, then the compiler complains `No implicit view available from Double => Float`. It feels kinda strange that it'd do this, since Scala handles `Double * Float`, and `+` does do the right thing in the case of adding `Float` and `Double` vectors. Or does Double specifically handle this case itself?